# how decrease python3.5.1 to python3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

python version that is on my linux (arch) is python3.5.1 and python2.7.11

I want to switch to python3.4
how can I do that?
I try to install on terminal but it faild

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It is not advisable to downgrade the system Python version, but you can install a second version of Python, then use either one using a virtualenv.

Comment: I want run django-cms and it does not support on python3.5

Comment: I try virtualenv but I could not match the\at python version that I want

Comment: @sahar According to [this](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/4633) and [this](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/4539) ticket, django-cms has no problems with Python 3.5, but Django versions older than 1.8 (1.9 officially) do. Are you using Django 1.7 with django-cms? In that case, you should consider upgrading Django instead (note that Django 1.7 has no security support any more, so you should upgrade anyway).

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would highly recommend using a virtual environment system like virtualenv or anaconda/miniconda when dealing with multiple versions of anything. [Anaconda docs](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html#use-a-different-version-of-python) [Virtualenv example from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv#1534343).

This means that you can do either `source activate <env name>` or `./bin/activate` for anaconda and virtualenv. Then each "install" of python gets its own set of packages, meaning that they're completely isolated.

Doing this also lets you run your own customized environments without having to mess with the main install, which is awesome especially on systems you don't "own".

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use those commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3.5
sudo apt-get install python3.(version)
```